# $q$-binomial sum, slightly

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, combinatorial-identities

Recall that $[n]_{q}!=\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{1-q^{j}}{1-q}$ and $\binom{n}k_{q}=\frac{[n]_{q}!}{[k]_{q}![n-k]_{q}!}$. Then the $q$-binomial theorem states
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k_qq^{\binom{k}2}=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+q^k).$$
I wanted to make a slight change to this and ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is there a formula for the following? What is its combinatorial interpretation, if any?
> $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k_{q^2}q^{3k}.$$

Comment: For what it's worth, assuming I haven't typoed then plugging the $n=5$ into Wolfram Alpha, expanding out and then factoring gives the result $(q + 1)^3 (q^2 + 1) (q^2 - q + 1) (q^4 + 1) (q^4 - q^3 + q^2 - q + 1) (q^6 - q + 1)$ which certainly has a number of nice factors at least ($[3]_{-q}$ and $[5]_{-q}$ stand out); recombining these I see $(q+1)(q^2+1)(q^3+1)(q^4+1)(q^5+1)(q^6-q+1)$ which is _very_ crisp looking. Where'd you come across this?

Comment: Doing the same for $n=4$ gives $(q+1)(q^2+1)(q^3+1)(q^4+1)(q^5-q+1)$ which is starting to look _very_ suspicious. Letting $\mathrm{Bin}[n]_q$ be the q-binomial product, this looks to possibly be $\mathrm{Bin}[n+1]_q-q\mathrm{Bin}[n]_q$? (ETA: modulo a potential off-by-one error, of course)

Comment: (Speaking of which, I think your product in the q-Binomial theorem is slightly off? As written, the first term on the RHS is 2 which is clearly not the constant coefficient of the LHS.)

Comment: why $3k$ exponent?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, your suspicions hold for $n$ up to 20, so it seems that the desired answer is $ (q^{n+1} - q + 1)\prod_{k=1}^n (q^k + 1)$ and what remains is to prove it. But the q-binomial theorem as given in the question is correct. Terms $k=0$ and $k=1$ both contribute 1 to the constant coefficient on the LHS.

Comment: For an odd positive integer $a$ define $f_a(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}_{q^2}q^{ak}$.  The given question concerns $f_3(n)$. Then $f_5(n)$ seems to exhibit similar behavior, while $f_7(n)$ is somewhat more complicated but perhaps still tractable. On the other hand, the sums $\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}_{q^3}q^{2k}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}_{q^3}q^{5k}$ do not look nice.

Comment: @RichardStanley: we are on the same track. I agree about the even powers $f_{2a}$ (non-tractable). For odd powers, $f_{2a+1}(n)$, it appears that sum is a finite linear combination (polynomials in $q$ as coefficients) of quantities of the form $g_1(n), g_1(n+1), g_1(n+2), \dots$ where $g_1(n)=f_1(n+1)-qf_1(n)$. Of course, $f_1(n)$ being $(-q;q)_n$.

Comment: @RichardStanley: perhaps, you like to look into the below answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_{n,a}(q)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k_{q^2}q^{ak}$ and $(-q;q)_n=(1+q)(1+q^2)\cdots(1+q^n)$.

The familiar recurrence
$\binom{n+1}k_{q^2}=\binom{n}k_{q^2}+q^{2n+2-2k}\binom{n}{k-1}_{q^2}$, the symmetry $\binom{n}k_{q^2}=\binom{n}{n-k}_{q^2}$ followed by the replacement $k\rightarrow n-k$ (in the sum) give out
\begin{align} f_{n+1,1}(q)&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}k_{q^2}q^k+\binom{n}{k-1}_{q^2}q^{2n+2-k}
=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k_{q^2}q^k+q^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k_{q^2}q^{n-k} \\
&=f_{n,1}(q)+q^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{n-k}_{q^2}q^{n-k}=(1+q^{n+1})f_{n,1}(q).
\end{align}
We arrive at $f_{n,1}(q)=(-q;q)_n$, inductively. Let's turn to $f_{n,3}(q)$ for which one invokes the recurrence
$\binom{n+1}k_{q^2}=q^{2k}\binom{n}k_{q^2}+\binom{n}{k-1}_{q^2}$. Proceed the same as above to obtain
\begin{align} 
f_{n+1,1}(q)&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}k_{q^2}q^{3k}+\binom{n}{k-1}_{q^2}q^k
=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k_{q^2}q^{3k}+q\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k_{q^2}q^k \\
&=f_{n,3}(q)+qf_{n,1}(q).
\end{align}
That means $f_{n,3}(q)=(-q;q)_{n+1}-q(-q;q)_n$ answers my question.

Motivated by Richard Stanley's comments, one may emulate our argument to compute $f_{n,a}(q)$ for $a$ odd. Here is the assertion: denote the *elementary symmetric polynomials* by $e_0=1$ and $e_j(x_1,\dots,x_m)=\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_j\leq m}x_{i_1}\cdots x_{i_j}$ for $1\leq j\leq m$. Then,
$$f_{n,2a+1}(q)=\sum_{j=0}^{a-1}(-1)^j\,e_j(q^3,q^5,\dots,q^{2a-1})\cdot h_{n+a-j-1}(q)$$
where $h_n(q):=(-q;q)_{n+1}-q(-q;q)_n=f_{n,3}(q)$.

I would like to leave the proof to the interested reader.